# Mac OS X: custom HID driver

Tags: macos, kernel, hid

I'm involved in developing of custom HID device support for Mac OS.
However it's not HID-complaint, i.e. it's grabbed by IOUSBCompositeDriver.

The device is supposed to be used as input device (keyboard, mouse) therefore I'm trying to implement driver as kext. I've tried to subclass IOUSBHIDDriver and IOHIDDevice returning following report descriptor (taken from Windows team) from newReportDescriptor() method:

```
const unsigned char g_ReportDescriptor[] = {
// Keyboard report   
0x05, 0x01,                         // USAGE_PAGE (Generic Desktop)
0x09, 0x06,                         // USAGE (Keyboard)
0xa1, 0x01,                         // COLLECTION (Application)
0x85, REPORTID_KEYBOARD,            //   REPORT_ID (Keyboard)    
0x05, 0x07,                         //   USAGE_PAGE (Keyboard)
0x19, 0xe0,                         //   USAGE_MINIMUM (Keyboard LeftControl)
0x29, 0xe7,                         //   USAGE_MAXIMUM (Keyboard Right GUI)
0x15, 0x00,                         //   LOGICAL_MINIMUM (0)
0x25, 0x01,                         //   LOGICAL_MAXIMUM (1)
0x75, 0x01,                         //   REPORT_SIZE (1)
0x95, 0x08,                         //   REPORT_COUNT (8)
0x81, 0x02,                         //   INPUT (Data,Var,Abs)
0x95, 0x01,                         //   REPORT_COUNT (1)
0x75, 0x08,                         //   REPORT_SIZE (8)
0x81, 0x03,                         //   INPUT (Cnst,Var,Abs)
0x95, 0x05,                         //   REPORT_COUNT (5)
0x75, 0x01,                         //   REPORT_SIZE (1)
0x05, 0x08,                         //   USAGE_PAGE (LEDs)
0x19, 0x01,                         //   USAGE_MINIMUM (Num Lock)
0x29, 0x05,                         //   USAGE_MAXIMUM (Kana)
0x91, 0x02,                         //   OUTPUT (Data,Var,Abs)
0x95, 0x01,                         //   REPORT_COUNT (1)
0x75, 0x03,                         //   REPORT_SIZE (3)
0x91, 0x03,                         //   OUTPUT (Cnst,Var,Abs)
0x95, 0x06,                         //   REPORT_COUNT (6)
0x75, 0x08,                         //   REPORT_SIZE (8)
0x15, 0x00,                         //   LOGICAL_MINIMUM (0)
0x25, 0x65,                         //   LOGICAL_MAXIMUM (101)
0x05, 0x07,                         //   USAGE_PAGE (Keyboard)
0x19, 0x00,                         //   USAGE_MINIMUM (Reserved (no event indicated))
0x29, 0x65,                         //   USAGE_MAXIMUM (Keyboard Application)
0x81, 0x00,                         //   INPUT (Data,Ary,Abs)
0xc0,                               // END_COLLECTION

// Relative Mouse report
0x05, 0x01,                         // USAGE_PAGE (Generic Desktop)
0x09, 0x02,                         // USAGE (Mouse)
0xa1, 0x01,                         // COLLECTION (Application)
0x85, REPORTID_RELATIVE_MOUSE,      //   REPORT_ID (Mouse)
0x09, 0x01,                         //   USAGE (Pointer)
0xa1, 0x00,                         //   COLLECTION (Physical)
0x05, 0x09,                         //     USAGE_PAGE (Button)
0x19, 0x01,                         //     USAGE_MINIMUM (Button 1)
0x29, 0x05,                         //     USAGE_MAXIMUM (Button 5)
0x15, 0x00,                         //     LOGICAL_MINIMUM (0)
0x25, 0x01,                         //     LOGICAL_MAXIMUM (1)
0x75, 0x01,                         //     REPORT_SIZE (1)
0x95, 0x05,                         //     REPORT_COUNT (5)
0x81, 0x02,                         //     INPUT (Data,Var,Abs)
0x95, 0x03,                         //     REPORT_COUNT (3)
0x81, 0x03,                         //     INPUT (Cnst,Var,Abs)
0x05, 0x01,                         //     USAGE_PAGE (Generic Desktop)
0x09, 0x30,                         //     USAGE (X)
0x09, 0x31,                         //     USAGE (Y)
0x15, 0x81,                         //     Logical Minimum (-127)
0x25, 0x7F,                         //     Logical Maximum (127)
0x75, 0x08,                         //     REPORT_SIZE (8)
0x95, 0x02,                         //     REPORT_COUNT (2)
0x81, 0x06,                         //     INPUT (Data,Var,Rel)
0x05, 0x01,                         //     Usage Page (Generic Desktop)
0x09, 0x38,                         //     Usage (Wheel)
0x15, 0x81,                         //     Logical Minimum (-127)
0x25, 0x7F,                         //     Logical Maximum (127)
0x75, 0x08,                         //     Report Size (8)
0x95, 0x01,                         //     Report Count (1)
0x81, 0x06,                         //     Input (Data, Variable, Relative)
0xc0,                               //   END_COLLECTION
0xc0,                               // END_COLLECTION


// Control report
0x06, 0x00, 0xff,              // USAGE_PAGE (Vendor Defined Page 1)
0x09, 0x01,                    // USAGE (Vendor Usage 1)
0xa1, 0x01,                    // COLLECTION (Application)
0x85, REPORTID_VXYCONTROL,     //   REPORT_ID ()
0x15, 0x00,                    //   LOGICAL_MINIMUM (0)
0x26, 0xff, 0x7f,              //   LOGICAL_MAXIMUM (32767)
0x75, 0x10,                    //   REPORT_SIZE (16)
0x95, 0x02,                    //   REPORT_COUNT (2)
0x09, 0x01,                    //   USAGE (Vendor Usage 1)
0x91, 0x00,                    //   OUTPUT (Data,Ary,Abs)
0xc0,                          // END_COLLECTION

// Trigger Macro report
0x06, 0x00, 0xff,              // USAGE_PAGE (Vendor Defined Page 1)
0x09, 0x02,                    // USAGE (Vendor Usage 2)
0xa1, 0x01,                    // COLLECTION (Application)
0x85, REPORTID_MACROTRIG,      //   REPORT_ID (5)
0x15, 0x00,                    //   LOGICAL_MINIMUM (0)
0x26, 0xff, 0x00,              //   LOGICAL_MAXIMUM (255)
0x75, 0x08,                    //   REPORT_SIZE (8)
0x95, 0x01,                    //   REPORT_COUNT (1)
0x09, 0x02,                    //   USAGE (Vendor Usage 2)
0x81, 0x02,                    //   INPUT (Data,Var,Abs)
0xc0                           // END_COLLECTION

};
```

and then feeding following structure to handleReport() method

```
#define KBD_KEY_CODES        6

#pragma pack(1)
typedef struct _VHID_KEYBOARD_REPORT
{
    UInt8      ReportID;
    // Left Control, Left Shift, Left Alt, Left GUI
    // Right Control, Right Shift, Right Alt, Right GUI
    UInt8      ShiftKeyFlags;
    UInt8      Reserved;
    UInt8      KeyCodes[KBD_KEY_CODES];
} VHID_KEYBOARD_REPORT;

VHID_KEYBOARD_REPORT keyboardReport;

bzero(&keyboardReport, sizeof(keyboardReport));
keyboardReport.ReportID = REPORTID_KEYBOARD;
keyboardReport.ShiftKeyFlags = 0;
keyboardReport.KeyCodes[0] = kHIDUsage_KeyboardA;

IOBufferMemoryDescriptor *report = IOBufferMemoryDescriptor::withBytes(&keyboardReport, sizeof(keyboardReport), kIODirectionInOut);

handleReport(report);
```

However I don't see any effect of that. I've expected that key press event would be generated.

What am I missing? What would be the general workflow for such kind of driver?

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot of things to go wrong here… starting with your info.plist's IOKitPersonalities… and OSBundleLibraries (do all your versions match?) Do you know that your kext is matching? (can you kextload/kextstat your driver?) Assuming that's good how are you replacing the report descriptor? Assuming that you're overriding ::newReportDescriptor correctly (did you call super::newReportDescriptor?) how are you returning your new descriptor?

```
IOBufferMemoryDescriptor* memDesc = IOBufferMemoryDescriptor::withBytes(& g_ReportDescriptor, sizeof(g_ReportDescriptor), kIODirectionOutIn, false);
```

It may help to sprinkle a few IOLog's thru your code to ensure everything is happening as you expect.

Comment: Yes! My kext is matched by OS and is loaded. 

I'm overriding newReportDescriptor with following code:
`{
    IOLog("New Report Descriptor\n");
    
    *descriptor = IOBufferMemoryDescriptor::withBytes(&g_ReportDescriptor, sizeof(g_ReportDescriptor), kIODirectionInOut);

    return kIOReturnSuccess;
}
`
At the moment I'm only trying to generate the event, therefore I'm calling handleReport() from start() method. I would still expect the event will be generated.

Comment: I don't think that calling handleReport from the start method will work (since it doesn't really have a report to handle).

Comment: My best advice is to contact dts @ apple.com (no spaces) for an 'official' answer. Send your project if possible.

Comment: I was under the impression that making `report` (2nd part of OP) and feeding it to `handleReport(report)` method would make HID system to process that report according to Report Descriptor.